# Non-transient non-serializable instance field in a non serializable class?

Tags: java, swing, serialization

I have a class without extending Serializable or Externalizable interface but still I am getting the bug while using FindBugs in netbeans. Can anyone suggest me how how to resolve this?

This is my class

```
public class Analyzer extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ItemListener, KeyListener{

public AnalyzerVariable [] objAnalyzerVar = new AnalyzerVariable [3];
public AnalyzerVariable objAnalyzerDataTypeInfo;

}
```

Bug from FindBug : class Analyzer defines a non-transient non-serializable instance field objAnalyzerVar and also same for objAnalyzerDataTypeInfo;

Comment: Yet another FindBugs anomaly. Just make an exception of it in the ruleset. There's a specific warning in the Javadoc of every Swing component *against* serializing them, and only a madman would actually try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`public class Analyzer extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ItemListener, KeyListener{...`

`Analyser` is a sub-class `javax.swing.JPanel`.
Since `javax.swing.JPanel` is a `Serializable` class, `Analyser` is also `Serializable`. So `Findbugs` is giving showing that as a bug.

More on `javax.swing.JPanel`- [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

Comment: You have 3 options. 1. Make `AnalyzerVariable` serializable. 2. Mark `AnalyzerVariable` type member as `transient` if it can be recomputed. 3. As @EJP pointed out, add an exception to Findbug ruleset.